# Android MutableLiveData initialization for Boolean

Tags: java, android

I'm able to initialize Android MutableLiveData for Integer as follows:

```
    // Create a LiveData with an Integer
    private MutableLiveData<Integer> intFoo;

    public MutableLiveData<Integer> intFoo() {
        if (intFoo == null) {
            intFoo = new MutableLiveData<>(42);
        }
        return intFoo;
    }
```

But, for Boolean?  (tried Boolean.FALSE too)

```
    // Create a LiveData with a Boolean
    private MutableLiveData<Boolean> boolFoo;

    public MutableLiveData<Boolean> boolFoo() {
        if (boolFoo == null) {
            boolFoo = new MutableLiveData<>(false);    <---- "Expected 0 arguments but found 1"
            // since above did not work changed to:
            // boolFoo = new MutableLiveData<>();
            // boolFoo.setValue(false);  
        }
        return boolFoo;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the source code for MutableliveData and found that the constructor for MutableLiveData has been removed, meaning you can only use the default constructor. Therefore to initialise, you can try creating an empty MutableLiveData of your type and use the setValue method to set the initial value of the MutableLiveData.

```
 boolFoo = new MutableLiveData<Boolean>();
 boolFoo.setValue(Boolean.valueOf(false));
```

Comment: Now I wonder why?  Anyway that's it and thanks for the answer!